# Loading GeoTIFF altimetry file created from GDAL or QGIS into a GeoServer failed

Tags: qgis, geoserver, geotiff-tiff, gdal-translate

GeoServer version : 2.18.2
GDAL version : 3.1.4
QGIS version : 3.16.3

I have a GeoTIFF altimetry file  with some missing data which is loaded perfectly in my GeoServer. I just extracted a new GeoTIFF with a more restrictive geographic extent to avoid the missing data using QGIS or gdal_translate and I don't succeed to put it on my GeoServer. I get the following error :

```
Failed to create reader from file://C:\newAlt.tif and hints Hints: LENIENT_DATUM_SHIFT = true FORCE_AXIS_ORDER_HONORING = http FEATURE_FACTORY = org.geotools.feature.LenientFeatureFactoryImpl@c7a975a COMPARISON_TOLERANCE = 1.0E-8 GRID_COVERAGE_FACTORY = GridCoverageFactory TILE_ENCODING = null EXECUTOR_SERVICE = java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@3c9ebbd3[Running, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0] STYLE_FACTORY = StyleFactoryImpl FORCE_LONGITUDE_FIRST_AXIS_ORDER = true FILTER_FACTORY = FilterFactoryImpl REPOSITORY = org.geoserver.catalog.CatalogRepository@431f67ec
```

Here is the result of the gdalinfo on the working geotiff :

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: alt.tif
Size is 20866, 13572
Coordinate System is:
PROJCRS["Google Maps Global Mercator",
    BASEGEOGCRS["WGS 84",
        DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
            ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
        ID["EPSG",4326]],
    CONVERSION["Popular Visualisation Pseudo-Mercator",
        METHOD["Popular Visualisation Pseudo Mercator",
            ID["EPSG",1024]],
        PARAMETER["Latitude of natural origin",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8801]],
        PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8802]],
        PARAMETER["False easting",0,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8806]],
        PARAMETER["False northing",0,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8807]]],
    CS[Cartesian,2],
        AXIS["easting (X)",east,
            ORDER[1],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
        AXIS["northing (Y)",north,
            ORDER[2],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
    USAGE[
        SCOPE["unknown"],
        AREA["World - 85┬░S to 85┬░N"],
        BBOX[-85.06,-180,85.06,180]],
    ID["EPSG",900913]]
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 1,2
Origin = (-331222.980063206865452,6048234.182797121815383)
Pixel Size = (1.475092908205949,-1.475092908205949)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  ( -331222.980, 6048234.183) (  2d58'31.54"W, 47d38'47.16"N)
Lower Left  ( -331222.980, 6028214.222) (  2d58'31.54"W, 47d31'30.48"N)
Upper Right ( -300443.691, 6048234.183) (  2d41'56.15"W, 47d38'47.16"N)
Lower Right ( -300443.691, 6028214.222) (  2d41'56.15"W, 47d31'30.48"N)
Center      ( -315833.336, 6038224.202) (  2d50'13.84"W, 47d35' 8.94"N)
Band 1 Block=20866x1 Type=Float32, ColorInterp=Gray
```

Here is the result on the extracted one (not working in geoserver) :

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: newAlt.tif
Size is 11000, 7000
Coordinate System is:
PROJCRS["Google_Maps_Global_Mercator",
    BASEGEOGCRS["WGS 84",
        DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
            ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
            ID["EPSG",6326]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]]],
    CONVERSION["unnamed",
        METHOD["Popular Visualisation Pseudo Mercator",
            ID["EPSG",1024]],
        PARAMETER["Latitude of natural origin",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8801]],
        PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8802]],
        PARAMETER["False easting",0,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8806]],
        PARAMETER["False northing",0,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8807]]],
    CS[Cartesian,2],
        AXIS["(E)",east,
            ORDER[1],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,
                ID["EPSG",9001]]],
        AXIS["(N)",north,
            ORDER[2],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,
                ID["EPSG",9001]]]]
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 1,2
Origin = (-322372.422613971168175,6042333.811164298094809)
Pixel Size = (1.475092908205949,-1.475092908205949)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  ( -322372.423, 6042333.811) (  2d53'45.31"W, 47d36'38.56"N)
Lower Left  ( -322372.423, 6032008.161) (  2d53'45.31"W, 47d32'53.31"N)
Upper Right ( -306146.401, 6042333.811) (  2d45' 0.58"W, 47d36'38.56"N)
Lower Right ( -306146.401, 6032008.161) (  2d45' 0.58"W, 47d32'53.31"N)
Center      ( -314259.412, 6037170.986) (  2d49'22.95"W, 47d34'45.97"N)
Band 1 Block=11000x1 Type=Float32, ColorInterp=Gray
```

Comment: Any idea ? I'm a little lost with all the verbosity of the GeoServer error message

Comment: You need to turn up the logging level to developer in the global settings page, and then make the request again. Then [edit] your question with the **relevant** part of the log file.